# How to convert x,y coordinates to work with absolute display?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, math

I receive X,Y coordinates from an API call. They look like this:

```
x: "-0.0120956897735595703"
y: "0.147876381874084473"
```

I've set the display on each of these minimap images to be absolute. I'm setting the "left" and "top" properties to be the X and Y coordinates like so: `style={{left: player.x, top: player.y}}` but it seems like the numbers are too small to do anything. Right now all the images are displayed in the top left corner because the x and y coordinates are too small.

[image: Div with a background of the minimap, and multiple minimap icons that are stuck in one place]

My question is, what type of coordinates are these in my API call and how do I convert them to CSS friendly values for "Top and "Left" so that they are accurate displayed on my minimap?

Code of my component for reference:

```
const Minimap = (props) => {
  const { players } = props.data.data
  return (
      <div style={mapStyle} className="realMinimapContainer">
      {players.map(player => {
        const heroName = localizedList[player.hero_id].replace('npc_dota_hero_', '');
        return (
          <img
          style={{left: player.x, top: player.y}}
          className="mapIcon" src={
            player.hero_id === 126 || player.hero_id === 128 ?
            newHeroes[player.hero_id] :
            `http://cdn.dota2.com/apps/dota2/images/heroes/${heroName}_icon.png`
      }></img>
        )
      })}
      </div>
  )
}
```

After following the advice of @FelipeMateusMalara below, it seems like I got close, but the images are quite a bit off.

Here you can see where the images are, I drew a red arrow showing where they should be:

[image: Picture showing where the icons are, red arrow showing where they should be]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just multiply these numbers by 100 and add 50 to each, this would result in the correct position of them in the map, and the result of the x expression you would set the **left** css directive, and the result of the y expression you would set the **bottom** css directive, both as percentage.

Why's that?

It's because your **origin** for both of these directives is the 50% mark and not the 0, so, you just have to transform the numbers given in percentages (multiplying by 100) and add the 50% missing

Comment: Wow! This is awesome, it worked great. If i want to tweak it a little, how would i do so? I think the icons are just a little off and I need to move them up a little.

Comment: That's nice, I'm glad for helping. Since you're drawing icons on the image (as far I as understood) you could increase the size of the icon to diminish this incoherence effect

Comment: it seems like the icons are quite a bit off. I added an image to the post to show where they currently are, and where they should be.

Comment: I updated the picture. It seems like the icons are inverted. I feel like this can be fixed by changing "left" and bottom"

I drew red arrows showing where the icons should be. What would you recommend here? EDIT - I am stupid. I had it set to top and not bottom.

Comment: Cool man, so it's solved? If you want we can discuss more in chat

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the coordinates you received from the API call are normalized coordinates, so they are between -1 to 1, which the negative number of the x-coordinate indicates. The coordinate origin of the API coordinate system seems to be in the middle while your display coordinate system has its origin in the top left corner. You have to multiply the coordinates with the size of your display and shift them accordingly to your display origin:

```
player.x = (API.x + 1) * display.width
player.y = (API.y + 1) * display.height
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

My width and height are 600px. Would i multiply by 600 and then add `px` to the end? Also should I use the left and top attributes for the coordinates?

Comment: You can do left: calc((api.x + 1) * 600px), top: calc((api.y + 1) * 600px)

Comment: I just tried it but it said `calc is undefined`.   ```<img
          style={{left: calc((player.x + 1) * '600px'), top: calc((player.y + 1) * '600px') }}
          className="mapIcon" src=...```

Comment: Looked into calc and wrapped it in quotes like so, but the images are now just stuck outside the minimap on the bottom right in a little bunch: ```          style={{left: `calc((${player.x} + 1) * 600px)`, top: `calc((${player.y} + 1) * 600px)` }}```

Comment: Try with (display.width / 2), so 300px instead of 600px, so half of the display size

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to tell from the information you've provided. I can guess that these numbers are deltas and not an offset (that you could just multiple by the width/height - since one of the numbers you've shown in negative).  I'd suggest that you look in the debugger (what tools are you using?) and see if there is not another x/y coordinate provided. Or possible You could just keep updating a global variable with your delta coordinates however I doubt that is the direction you want to go.

Comment: I see. These are the only coordinates I receive from the API call. What do you mean by "multiply by the width/height"? How would i do that?

Comment: Multiplying won't work. Something like canvas.width * player.x.  Your coordinates are not between -1 and 1. I believe that these are deltas, but cannot tell from the data you've provided. If you want to solve this issue you need to provide more information. Short of that, look at whatever debugger you have and explore what data you have. If there is no other data then you've hooked the wrong function.